# Why the error 'class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 57.0' produces only in IntelliJ and not in STS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite, intellij-14

Why does the error

```
class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 57.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

only produces in IntelliJ. I read about the error and it fixes, and most of the solutions seem to upgrade the Java version as Spring 4 is only compatible with Java version >= 17 **but if I run the same piece of code in STS Eclipse, it successfully runs with no issues without changing anything. Why does this happen?**

Following is the **pom.xml** for the **Maven-based spring boot project**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.quotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>quotation-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>quotation-backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

[image: IntelliJ error screenshot]
*P.S - I have **community version** of IntelliJ and JDK as **OpenJDK13U-jdk_x64 from AdoptOpenJDK**. Also, I have very little experience with Spring.
Thanks in advance.

For the solution, I tried searching over the web but didn't get about the differences between the 2 IDEs. Everywhere I searched for the problem, it said to upgrade jdk to version 17 or greater, but that's not the case I want. I want the dev to happen how it is working in STS IDE.

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0.X+ requires JDK17... that means you have to upgrade your community version of IntelliJ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have the latest IntelliJ community version installed recently and same result

Comment: This: `<java.version>11</java.version>` does not work... and will never work as I mentioned already Spring 3.0.X+ requires JDK17+... no way to change that....

Comment: @khmarbaise. Thank you for your answer. Can you comment on this - but if I run the same piece of code in STS Eclipse, it successfully runs with no issues without changing anything. Why does this happen?

Comment: Which version of STS Eclipse do you use?

Comment: Spring Tool Suite 4 

Version: 4.18.0.RELEASE

Comment: Maybe you run the project on a JDK17 when using STS?

Comment: Which JDK is being in Eclipse(STS)?

Comment: @khmarbaise - Although I have  OpenJDK13 installed in the system, I have modified my pom.xml to <java.version>11</java.version> post unzipping the project, which while creating the project from 'https://start.spring.io/' was <java.version>17</java.version>

Comment: you have to configurate to use JDK17 in all cases ... it does not help having JDK13 etc. you have to have JDK17... in Eclipse etc. as well as on command line... Spring Boot 3+ required JDK17 as minimum...